# Microcontroller driven circuit that opens a charging circuit and closes a resistive circuit simultaneously from the same I/O pin

Tags: microcontroller, capacitor, raspberry-pi, mosfet-driver, darlington

I'm working on a project that charges a capacitor with an external 5V DC power supply and then discharges it across a very low resistance. Since I don't want to close the circuit while the power supply is in-line with the load, I'm trying to design a circuit that would simultaneously close the loop between the capacitor and the load while opening the loop between the capacitors and the power supply. I'm working with a microcontroller with a max voltage output of 3.3V. I've been trying some different designs, and fundamentally it should be made up of the following components:

1. An inverter circuit to invert the signal from the IO pin using S8050 or similar
2. A Darlington array (ULN2003 in this case) to drive a 5V signal to trigger the MOSFET and charge the capacitors
3. A power MOSFET (IRLB3034) as a switch to open or close the resistive circuit

But I'm having an extremely hard time getting all of the components to work together since I'm a novice. Which resistors to use, what considerations to take in when using multiple power sources in order to avoid damaging the microcontroller, if I need any additional components are holding me up from progressing with this, admittedly, simple circuit. How should I design a circuit like this and can I accomplish it with the components listed above?

EDIT:

I’m working on an art project that displays a sequence on a CRT that is powered by a Raspberry Pi. The RPi is also controlling a number of components (e.g., power LEDs, fans, spinning HDD) stored in an old desktop computer case to make it appear as if the sequence being displayed is coming from an old computer. The RPi is controlling an ATX power supply that is driving all of these components. At the very end of the sequence, the computer abruptly shuts off with a loud popping noise from a speaker within the tower, and smoke (or in this case vapor) starts pouring out of the desktop

The smoke machine is a low resistance nichrome coil (~0.2ohm) immersed in propylene glycol. I want the capacitors (5.4V 250F) to provide the power necessary to run a high current through the nichrome which in turn heats and generates vapor. I need the capacitors to discharge when the RPi tells it to, which would only occur when the ATX is off.

Since the ATX will be off and no longer charging the capacitors when they are meant to be discharged, throttling the charging current won't be necessary for this application, but I also don't want the capacitors discharging unless the RPi is providing a signal or both the RPi and the ATX are off.

[image: This is the circuit I'm currently working with]

Comment: Not sure I read correctly what you are trying to accomplish, you seems want to disconnect the load when charging the capacitor. Maybe you just need a [3-pin switch jack](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/90529/what-to-do-with-third-contact-in-dc-barrel-plug-with-only-two-input-contacts).

Comment: an SPDT switch would do that

Comment: `simultaneously close the loop between the capacitor and the load while opening the loop between the capacitors and the power supply` ... you really want that to be sequential, not simultaneous

Comment: Why don't you want to have the power supply in line with the discharging load? Is the power supply not current-limited? -- Just to feed our creativity, what use case is this?

Comment: I’m working on an art project that displays a sequence on a CRT that is powered by a Raspberry Pi. The RPi is also controlling a number of components (e.g., power LEDs, fans, spinning HDD) stored in an old desktop computer case to make it appear as if the sequence being displayed is coming from an old computer. The RPi is controlling an ATX power supply that is driving all of these components.  At the very end of the sequence, the computer abruptly shuts off with a loud popping noise from a speaker within the tower, and smoke (or in this case vapor) starts pouring out of the desktop

Comment: The smoke machine is a low resistance nichrome coil (~0.2ohm) immersed in propylene glycol. I want the capacitors (5.4V 250F) to provide the power necessary to run a high current through the nichrome which in turn heats and generates vapor. I need the capacitors to discharge when the RPi tells it to, which would only occur when the ATX is off.

Comment: Since the ATX will be off and no longer charging the capacitors when they are meant to be discharged, throttling the charging current won't be necessary for this application, but I also don't want the capacitors discharging unless the RPi is providing a signal or both the RPi and the ATX are off.

Comment: Here is [a copy of the circuit I'm working with](https://imgur.com/iXm9w8F)

Comment: Thanks for commenting. However, please add such information by [edit]ing your question.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f03lq1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The [IXDD609PI](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/240/IXD_609-1546213.pdf) is a gate driver to switch the two MOSFETs smartly. The [IPP120P04P4L03AKSA2](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IPP_B_I120P04P4L_03-DataSheet-v01_02-EN.pdf) is a hefty P-channel MOSFET. R1 represents whatever is limiting the capacitor charge current. If you don't add external resistance it will be limited by the power supply (internal resistance and current limit), capacitor ESR, wiring resistance, M1 MOSFET on resistance and wiring resistance.

Common ground between the ATX supply and MCU is assumed. Heavy currents flow in some of the wires so some layout care is called for. Even the gate currents can be several amperes (briefly), hence ceramic MLCC capacitor C2  placed close to the gate driver chip power pins. A few ohms in series with each gate might be a good idea (5 to 10 ohms) to slightly slow the switching.

Keep in mind that if M1 and/or M2 fails, it/they will likely fail shorted, so your device should deal with that in a safe manner.

The driver is non-inverting, so a 0V input signal results in the capacitor charging through M1 and (if present) R1, and a 3.3V input results in the capacitor discharging through R2 and M2.